# Virustotal says file is clean but PDFexaminer finds it suspicious

Tags: malware

I have spent some time reading other questions regarding PDFs and scanning them. PDFExaminer says that the file does "suspicious obfuscation using eval". I am using the latest version of adobe on protected mode with java script off, should I be worried of this PDF? I also have malwarebytes installed on my PC which also says the PDF is clean.

Answer (score 1):

Given that PDFExaminer uses heuristics to examine PDFs, some false positives are likely.  (I'm not sure exactly what it uses to detect the "obfuscation" with eval.)  On the other hand, given that virustotal and malwarebytes predominantly use signature-based engines, some false negatives are likely.  This combination leaves you, as you've noticed, in a middle ground.

If you need to read this PDF and are concerned, I'd consider opening it in a VM.  It's unlikely that they have both an unknown PDF exploit and a VM escape (unless you have reason to believe you're being targeted by a nation state).

If you're interested in learning more about malicious PDFs, I'd manually take a look at the details of the PDFExaminer findings and see what the PDF is doing with eval.  It could be it's some kind of watermarking or copy protection, which (though some people do not like such measures) poses no risk to the integrity of your PC.